# ampersand.js multiple view switchers

Tags: javascript, view, ampersand.js

I'm trying to work out how to have multiple view switchers so I can have different animation transitions.

In my Main.js view I'm able to use ampersand-view-switcher to call a model which carries out my page transition animations on "show" + "hide" and these are attached to my navigation.

```
render: function () {
    // some additional stuff we want to add to the document head
    document.head.appendChild(domify(templates.head()));

    var anim = new Anim();

    // main renderer
    this.renderWithTemplate({me: me});

    // init and configure our page switcher
    this.pageSwitcher = new ViewSwitcher(this.queryByHook('page-container'), {

        waitForRemove: true,

        show: function (newView) {
            // it's inserted and rendered for me
            document.title = _.result(newView, 'pageTitle') || 'cmdv portfolio';

            // add a class specifying it's active
            anim.fadeElIn(newView.el);
            anim.navUp();

            // store an additional reference, just because
            app.currentPage = newView;

        },

        hide: function (oldView, newView, cb) {

            anim.fadeElOut(oldView.el);
            anim.navDown();

            setTimeout(cb, 400);

        }
    });

    // setting a favicon for fun (note, it's dynamic)
    setFavicon('/images/ampersand.png');
    return this;
},
```

Now I'm trying to have a different view-switcher on a specific page.
This page will act like a gallery and when item clicked you will be taken to a different page but with another view-switcher animation.

Does anyone have any pointers as to how this could be accomplished.

Ampersand is a really great tool but can't find anything in the docs and the chatroom they have isn't geared to answering noobs.

Comment: cool noted, still a believer in politeness but guess that's not the norm anymore

Comment: Politeness is good in a conversation. But this is not a discussion forum. We're not having a conversation. It's a Q&A site, and we should stick closely to the Q and the A.

Comment: Did you try to add the viewSwitcher to your gallery view with different query hook?

Answer (score 1):

I think that following should answer your question. When you create new View Switcher, the first argument is the element inside of which your switched views will be rendered (it's `this.queryByHook('page-container')` in your case. Let's say you have some other view somewhere (for example, one of the views rendered with ViewSwitcher), and you want that view to have another view switcher. Then you should do the same thing as shown above: inside the `render` function you create new view switcher which you attach to some other element. For example, if in your view you have a div with `data-hook="another-view-switcher"`, you'd do:

```
this.pageSwitcher = new ViewSwitcher(this.queryByHook('another-view-switcher'), {//and so on
```

I know that this is the old question, but does my explanation answer it?